# rviz symbol lookup error

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I attempt to launch a simulation I get a symbol lookup error and a joint state publisher panel launches but not the main rviz window. The error I get is:

/opt/ros/groovy/lib/rviz/rviz: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/groovy/lib/librviz.so: undefined symbol: _ZN12class_loader11ClassLoader37has_unmananged_instance_been_created_E
[rviz-4] process has died [pid 4967, exit code 127, cmd /opt/ros/groovy/lib/rviz/rviz -d /home/frank/Documents/Robotics/clamArm_wrkspc/clam_catkin/src/clam_bringup/launch/rviz/clam_simulation.rviz __name:=rviz __log:=/home/frank/.ros/log/d32ca0f4-7615-11e2-b08c-001c7b74b70a/rviz-4.log].
log file: /home/frank/.ros/log/d32ca0f4-7615-11e2-b08c-001c7b74b70a/rviz-4*.log

Does anyone know what causes this or how to fix it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55135/rviz-symbol-lookup-error/) by [Conchords](https://answers.ros.org/users/4194/conchords/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-02-13

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rvlvrocelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/4217/rvlvrocelot/) on 2013-02-16**:
I am getting the exact same error, if you figure it out you should post :)

**Comment by [Yaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/18121/yaser/) on 2017-07-25**:
Similarly, I try to run rviz on kinetic and get the following error:
**/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/rviz/rviz: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/librviz.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK9QTreeView16viewportSizeHintEv**
Besides, I tried "dist-upgrade" but the problem is not solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran into this as well.  Problem is ros-groovy-class-loader is older than your ros-groovy-rviz.  The complete but slow solution is:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

This installs the latest version of every software package currently installed.  Can take hours if you haven't done it in a while.

The faster solution which just solves this one problem is:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-class-loader
```

The second one fixed it for me anyway.  I'll start the slow one just before I leave work.

---

Originally posted by [hersh](https://answers.ros.org/users/97/hersh/) with karma: 1351 on 2013-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/18121/yaser/) on 2017-07-25**:
Hi Hersh,
I am trying to run rviz on kinetic and I used "dist-upgrade", but it did not solve the problem.
I still get:
**/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/rviz/rviz: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/librviz.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK9QTreeView16viewportSizeHintEv**